# Order fields checkout

Tags: expresso-store, members, fields

Best,

I want to make a checkout with exp-resso, if you are registered to the fields already filled in.

I do this in store-Fields,  Orders > settings-> Field Settings

The code what I use in ExpressionEngine can be found below.

```
{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="registed editform"
    next="webshop/checkout3"
    form_id="checkout"
    error_handling="inline"
}

    {if no_items}
        {redirect="webshop/checkout"}
    {/if}


 <div class="clear"></div>

  <section id="main" class="entire_width">
    <div class="container_12">      
       <div id="content">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <h1 class="page_title">Checkout</h1>
        </div><!-- .grid_12 -->


        <div class="grid_9" id="checkout_info">
            <ul class="checkout_list">
                <li class="active">
                    <div class="list_header">Gegevens<div class="number">1</div></div>
                        <div id="form_checkout">
                            <div class="error"><span></span></div>

                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Naam</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="billing_name" id="billing_name" value="{billing_name}" required />
                                </div>

                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Adres</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="billing_address1" id="billing_address1" value="{billing_address1}" required />
                                </div>

                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Postcode</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" value="{if billing_postcode}{billing_postcode}{/if}" required />
                                </div>

                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Gemeente</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="billing_city" id="billing_city" value="{billing_city}" required />
                                </div>

                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Land</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <select name="billing_country">
                                        {billing_country_options}
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Telefoonnummer</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" value="{billing_phone}" required />
                                </div>

                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>E-mailadres</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="{order_email}" required />
                                </div>
                            <div class="email">
                                <strong>Verzendmethode</strong><sup class="surely">*</sup><br/>
                                    <select name="shipping_method" required>
                                        {shipping_method_options}
                                </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="submit">                                        
                            <input type="submit" name="next" value="Volgende" class="bay" />

                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="list_header">Betaling<div class="number">2</div></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="list_header">Bevestigen<div class="number">3</div></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
                </div><!-- .grid_9 -->
       </div><!-- #content -->

      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- .container_12 -->
  </section><!-- #main -->

  <div class="clear"></div>
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

I see the value do not appear when I logged in, can anyone help?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Below you will find a screenshots, it's so that the value is not visible when you're logged in at the checkout form.

[image: Settings order fields]

[image: Checkout page]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean you have member fields mapped to order fields but the form is not being automatically populated with the member's fields?

Comment: Have you mapped the member fields under Store > Settings > Order Fields? Can you upload a screenshot of that page? Also, are you emptying the cart between each test? The mapped member fields are only loaded once per cart.

Comment: Hi Bert. I've replied to your support email so let me know if you're still having problems. Also, just so you're aware, the usual practice is to use this comment space for follow-ups to your original question. Only post something as an answer if it actually answers the question.